# How do I zoom in automatically to the current location in Google Maps API for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have integrated the Google Maps API in Android Studio, and it also finds the current location, but I want to increase the zoom level, so that I can view my current location more clearly and precised. How do I increase the zoom level?

You can find my code below:

```
package com.example.umar.testgoogle;

import android.location.Location;

import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is
                            // not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play
     * services APK is correctly installed) and the map has not already
     * been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever call
     * {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a
     * prompt for the user to install/update the Google Play services
     * APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the
     * prompt and correctly installing/updating/enabling the Google
     * Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not have been
     * completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it
     * would only be stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may
     * not be called again so we should call this method in
     * {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move
     * the camera. In this case, we just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure
     *  that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                    this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            }
            catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " +
                       connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Change from:

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
```

to:

```
float zoomLevel = 16.0f; //This goes up to 21
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));
```

> **public static CameraUpdate newLatLngZoom (LatLng latLng, float zoom)**
>
> Returns a CameraUpdate that moves the center of the screen to a
>   latitude and longitude specified by a LatLng object, and moves to the
>   given zoom level.
>
> Parameters latLng a LatLng object containing the desired latitude and
>   longitude. zoom   the desired zoom level, in the range of 2.0 to 21.0.
>   Values below this range are set to 2.0, and values above it are set to
>   21.0. Increase the value to zoom in. Not all areas have tiles at the largest zoom levels. Returns a CameraUpdate containing the
>   transformation.

Comment: Just a small correction. First line is:
    float zoomLevel = (float) 16.0; //This goes up to 21

Answer (score 6):

or you can also use animateCamerma method to get an animated zooming effect.

```
//  This is method returns the lastKnownlocation and store it in location object from where then you can retrive latitute and longitude.
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 20.0f));
```