# Zoom map Get location chosen by User and pass it to activity

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps, android-gps

I have this code, that allows a user to select a location (mechanic_location) and passes it to another activity(mechanic_login). The problem is, it does not zoom. Help me enable it to zoom to the current location the user is in but give the user the ability to pick another location different from the one that he/she is in. Once the location is picked, click a button to send the latitude and longitude to the view (mechanic_login). Here is my code

```
public class mechanic_location extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Button mSendLocationBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mechanic_location);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("picked_point",latLng);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I zoom in automatically to the current location in Google Maps API for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868121/how-do-i-zoom-in-automatically-to-the-current-location-in-google-maps-api-for-an)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the moveCamera() Method and defined the zoom level

```
float zoomLevel = 16.0f; //This goes up to 21
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));
```

for mor information about using google map, you can check it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views)

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868356/8608614)